# How to make Orbeon autocomplete address from Google places API

Tags: autocomplete, google-places-api, orbeon

I need to use autocomplete field in Orbeon forms to search for an address from Google places API web service.

The chosen address from the autocomplete field should then fill the appropriate text fields in the form.

The functionality is demonstrated by google in the following Functional Example:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

I read in Orbeon Map documentation:
https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/map.html

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.xforms.xbl.fr.map.key" value="..."/>
```

I generated the key for Google Places API and not Google Maps API, is there a specific property name for "places"?

How can i make this autocomplete functionality to fill in the address text fields ?

Answer (score 0):

The Orbeon Forms [map component](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/map.html) exposes the functionality of Google Maps, or a certain subset thereof, as a component, which you can add to a form as a form field. Similarly, you would here need to build another component that works like an autocomplete querying the Google Places database.

For this, I wouldn't reuse any code from the Orbeon Forms autocomplete control. Instead, I would start by creating the control you want starting with a bank HTML page, independently of Orbeon Forms. Once you have it working the way you want, you can start packaging that code into an [XBL component](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xbl/tutorial.html).